# Form layout bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to achieve this form layout using bootstrap 3.
Here's a screenshot for the desired form and I can't seem to make it look alike:
[screenshot](http://i62.tinypic.com/1z31013.jpg)

PS: I'm new with bootstrap

And here's the code that i'm using

```html
<form class="form-horizontal row" role="form">
  <div class="form-group col-md-12">
<label for="inputType" class="col-xs-1 control-label">When:</label>
<div class="form-group has-feedback col-xs-2">
  <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" value="" placeholder="Date">
  <label class="form-control-feedback glyphicon glyphicon-calendar" for="login-pass"></label>
</div>
<label for="inputType" class="col-xs-1 control-label"></label>
<div class="form-group has-feedback col-xs-2">
  <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" value="" placeholder="Time">
  <label class="form-control-feedback glyphicon glyphicon-time" for="login-pass"></label>
</div>
<label for="inputType" class="col-xs-1 control-label">To</label>
<div class="form-group has-feedback col-xs-2">
  <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" value="" placeholder="Date">
  <label class="form-control-feedback glyphicon glyphicon-calendar" for="login-pass"></label>
</div>
<label for="inputType" class="col-xs-1 control-label"></label>
<div class="form-group has-feedback col-xs-2">
  <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" value="" placeholder="Time">
  <label class="form-control-feedback glyphicon glyphicon-time" for="login-pass"></label>
</div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-12">
<label for="inputType" class="col-xs-2 control-label">Time Zone:</label>
<div class="form-group has-feedback col-xs-2">
  <select class="select select-info select2-offscreen" data-toggle="select" tabindex="-1" title="">
    <option value="0" class="">GMT +1</option>
    <option value="1" class="">GMT +2</option>
    <option value="2" class="">GMT +3</option>
  </select>
</div>
<label for="inputType" class="col-xs-3 control-label">Reccurence:</label>
<div class="form-group has-feedback col-xs-2">
  <select class="select select-primary select2-offscreen" data-toggle="select" tabindex="-1" title="">
    <option value="0" class="">none</option>
    <option value="1" class="">Weekly</option>
  </select>
</div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: did you add a link to the bootstrap file in your html???

Comment: Doesn't directly answer your question which is why I'm only adding it as a comment, but have a look at [shoelace.io](http://shoelace.io/)  to create a skeleton for your bootstrap site

Comment: @TobyCannon thanks a lot for this tool it is really interesting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using `form-inline`.

Here's an example: http://www.bootply.com/ZW7elrtPmV

```
<form class="form-inline" role="form">
  <div class="form-group has-feedback">
    <label for="inputType" class="control-label">When:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" value="" placeholder="Date">
    <span class="form-control-feedback glyphicon glyphicon-calendar" for="login-pass"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group has-feedback">
    <label for="inputType" class="control-label"></label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" value="" placeholder="Time">
    <span class="form-control-feedback glyphicon glyphicon-time" for="login-pass"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group has-feedback">
    <label for="inputType" class="control-label">To</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" value="" placeholder="Date">
    <span class="form-control-feedback glyphicon glyphicon-calendar" for="login-pass"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group has-feedback">
    <label for="inputType" class="control-label"></label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" value="" placeholder="Time">
    <span class="form-control-feedback glyphicon glyphicon-time" for="login-pass"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputType" class="control-label">Time Zone:</label>
    <select class="select select-info select2-offscreen form-control input-sm" data-toggle="select" tabindex="-1" title="">
      <option value="0" class="">GMT +1</option>
      <option value="1" class="">GMT +2</option>
      <option value="2" class="">GMT +3</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputType" class="control-label">Reccurence:</label>
    <div class="form-group">
      <select class="select select-primary select2-offscreen form-control input-sm" data-toggle="select" tabindex="-1" title="">
        <option value="0" class="">none</option>
        <option value="1" class="">Weekly</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here you go: All you need to do it to add a link to your bootstrap file**- *Run the Code Snippet below.*

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form class="form-horizontal row" role="form">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                            <label for="inputType" class="col-xs-1 control-label">When:</label>
                            <div class="form-group has-feedback col-xs-2">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" value="" placeholder="Date">
                                <label class="form-control-feedback glyphicon glyphicon-calendar" for="login-pass"></label>
                            </div>
                            <label for="inputType" class="col-xs-1 control-label"></label>
                            <div class="form-group has-feedback col-xs-2">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" value="" placeholder="Time">
                                <label class="form-control-feedback glyphicon glyphicon-time" for="login-pass"></label>
                            </div>
                            <label for="inputType" class="col-xs-1 control-label">To</label>
                            <div class="form-group has-feedback col-xs-2">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" value="" placeholder="Date">
                                <label class="form-control-feedback glyphicon glyphicon-calendar" for="login-pass"></label>
                            </div>
                            <label for="inputType" class="col-xs-1 control-label"></label>
                            <div class="form-group has-feedback col-xs-2">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" value="" placeholder="Time">
                                <label class="form-control-feedback glyphicon glyphicon-time" for="login-pass"></label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                            <label for="inputType" class="col-xs-2 control-label">Time Zone:</label>
                            <div class="form-group has-feedback col-xs-2">
                                <select class="select select-info select2-offscreen" data-toggle="select" tabindex="-1" title="">
                                    <option value="0" class="">GMT +1</option>
                                    <option value="1" class="">GMT +2</option>
                                    <option value="2" class="">GMT +3</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <label for="inputType" class="col-xs-3 control-label">Reccurence:</label>
                            <div class="form-group has-feedback col-xs-2">
                                <select class="select select-primary select2-offscreen" data-toggle="select" tabindex="-1" title="">
                                    <option value="0" class="">none</option>
                                    <option value="1" class="">Weekly</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```